# Why is my PHP and HTML code not working?

Tags: php, html

There is this code that I am trying to write. The user is supposed to guess a random, odd number between 1 and 99 and the code is supposed to include both php and HTML codes.

This is the code I came up with:

```
<?php

$heading = "Welcome to the guessing game";
$num_to_guess = rand(1,99);
if(!isset($_POST['guess'])){
$message= "Welcome to the guessing game";

} elseif($_POST['guess'] %2==0) {
    $message= "The number you are guessing is not odd!!!";

} elseif($_POST['guess']< $num_to_guess){
    $message= "Your guess is smaller than the secret number";

}elseif($_POST['guess']> $num_to_guess){
    $message= "Your guess is bigger than the secret number";

} else($_POST['guess']= $num_to_guess){
    $message= "You guessed correctly.Now try to guess another number!";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Guessing Machine </title
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
Try to guess the odd number between 1 and 99 
<input type="hidden" name="number" value='value="<?php echo $number; ?>">

<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="check" value="check"/><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that the code is not completely correct, because it is not giving me the expected result. Can anyone tell me what exactly is wrong with my code? I am very confused. Thank you.

Comment: else can not have condition. Either remove that condition or put if with it
`else if($_POST['guess']= $num_to_guess){
    $message= "You guessed correctly.Now try to guess another number!";
}`

Comment: you have logical error in your code and you have syntax error too

Comment: You're on the right track. You need an input field for "guess" and beware that $number_to_guess should be random only the first time. If you draw it at every request, the game is impossible.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve with the hidden field is a good idea. But then  you should test again $_POST['number'] not against $num_to_guess. You could also use the session to "remember" the number to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last ELSEIF with the following codes:

`} elseif($_POST['guess']== $num_to_guess){`

Comment: No need to check the equality. If it's neither bigger nor smaller then it's equal.